# SAML Signing problems

Tags: xml, security, saml

We are facing problems to sign the content while using the following set of JARS for SAML.
opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar 
openws-1.4.2-1.jar
xmlsec-1.5.2.jar 
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar
These are the endorsed jars in the JBOSS:
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
jettison-1.3.1.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis-1.3.04.jar

In our SAML code `org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI` is the JSR provider we are using.
We are on jdk1.5.0_14. and jboss-4.2.3.GA.

Using the above set of versions the Digital signing is failing at         signature.sign(signContext);

Type of signature is `javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature`
Type of signContext is `javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext`

There is no exception thrown but the signing is failing and an empty response is given.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Saludos

Kartheek

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Why are you not using the OpenSAML signing methods?

Comment: Hi Stefan,This issue was resolved after removing the xmlsec.jar from the jboss client folder and jbossws-sar folders.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved after removing the xmlsec.jar from the jboss client folder and jbossws-sar folders.Thanks!